# Convert tab delimited data into dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm trying to convert an array with a dictionary to a flattened dictionary and export it to a JSON file. I have an initial tab-delimited file, and have tried multiple ways but not coming to the final result. If there is more than one row present then save these as arrays in the dictionary

```
Name        file    code    file_location
TESTLIB1    443     123     location1
TESTLIB2    444     124     location2
```

Current Output:

```
{'library': 'TESTLIB2', 'file': '444', 'code': '124', 'file_location': 'location2'}
```

Desired Output if num_lines > 1:

```
{'library': ['TEST1', 'TEST2'], 'file': ['443', '444'], 'code': ['123', 123], 'file_location': ['location1', 'location2]}
```

Code Snippet

```
data_dict = {}
with open('file.tmp') as input:
    reader = csv.DictReader(input, delimiter='\t')
    num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('write_object.tmp'))
    for row in reader:
        data_dict.update(row)
        if num_lines > 1:
            data_dict.update(row)
    with open('output.json', 'w') as output:
        output.write(json.dumps(data_dict))
    print(data_dict)
```

Comment: If you don't want to write your own code, load the file into a pandas dataframe and use `to_dict('list')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create `list` for each column and iterate to append row by row

```
import csv
import json    

# read file
d = {}
with open('write_object.tmp') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    headers = next(reader)
    for head in headers:
        d[head] = []
    for row in reader:
        for i, head in enumerate(headers):
            d[head].append(row[i])

# save as json file
with open('output.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(d, f)
```

output:

```
{'Name': ['TESTLIB1', 'TESTLIB2'],
 'file': ['443', '444'],
 'code': ['123', '124'],
 'file_location': ['location1', 'location2']}
```

Comment: @jaypeerachi, thanks for the help. Now I'm trying to modify your code, so it will not store the item in the array if there is just one column value. If not store in array if there is more than one column value.  {'Name': 'TESTLIB1',
 'file': ['443', '444'],
 'code': '123',
 'file_location': ['location1', 'location2']}

Comment: Do you mean to store in array only if there are more than 1 values in that column, right? So, a value can be `null`?

Comment: yes correct, should have clarified, but this should fill in as `NULL` automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from collections import defaultdict

data_dict = defaultdict(list)
with open('input-file') as inp:
     for row in csv.DictReader(inp, delimiter='\t'):
          for key, val in row.items():
              data_dict[key].append(val)
print(data_dict)
```

```
# output
{'Name': ['TESTLIB1', 'TESTLIB2'],
 'file': ['443', '444'],
 'code': ['123', '124'],
 'file_location': ['location1', 'location2']}
```